# Get multiple post content

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, search, custom-fields

So I am in the function.php file in the wordpress environment and I want to add a filter which allows one of my plugin to pick multiple custom field. To be more specific I have this Search plugin that show result in a dropdown menu whit images and a descriptions field on the right for each result. What I want is to fill the description field with a few custom field, shown one below the other as a list. I don't know much php so I don't know what I'm exactly doing wrong. Here my actually code:

```
add_filter( 'asl_results', 'asl_get_the_content_after', 10, 1 );
function asl_get_the_content_after( $results ) {
    
    // Parse through each result item
    foreach ($results as $k=>&$r) {
        if ( isset($r->post_type) ) {
            $r->content = get_post_field('year', $r->id);
            $r->content = get_post_field('color', $r->id);
            $r->content = get_post_field('price', $r->id);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

With this code the search result show up only the last one field. What I actually want is to show all this custom field in different row. I alredy tried to put everything in one custom field, but it doesn't consider space, putting all in one row. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected because inside the IF you are replacing the content, instead of concatenating it or adding it to an array. The correct thing would be:

```
if ( isset($r->post_type) ) {
    if ( !$r->content ) $r->content = '';
    $r->content .= get_post_field('year', $r->id) . "<br>";
    $r->content .= get_post_field('color', $r->id) . "<br>";
    $r->content .= get_post_field('price', $r->id) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Whit this code, it actually picks the three field and put them one under the other, but he take also the post content such as headline and text, that i don't want to show up. So whit this code I have like 4 row of content post and then the three custom field that i made. How remove the post content?

Comment: Just remove `if ( !$r->content ) $r->content = '';` from the code =)

Comment: Sorry, remove dot from first line. `$r->content = get_post_field('year', $r->id) . "<br>";`